# Should I work directly with Apollo data or save/modify it in Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

How should I work with data retrieved from an Apollo query?

My first thought was saving it in a redux store, modify it (reducing it with redux, using action creators) and then, when the data is ready (user clicks on "save" button), send a mutation to Apollo to update it on the server.

Nevertheless, I don't think that's the best approach. Should I avoid using a Redux store here and working directly with the Apollo imperative API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the docs about [updating the cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html)?

When sending a mutation for editing anything, usually you get the modified object as a response. When receiving that updated object, `react-apollo` automatically updates the corresponding locally stored object that corresponds to the same `id` and `__typename` that were received.

So, if when you use the `graphql` decorator on your components to inject them props from the Apollo store, when the store is updated as a result of a mutation or query, the props should be automatically passed again. No need to manually modify them.

There are certain cases where you need to use `store.readyQuery` and `store.writeQuery`, but they are edge cases and hopefully not too many.

Still, I'd say unless you're comfortable and have some time working with `react-apollo` to know how it works and what it's doing, it's probably better working *directly* with Apollo, instead of trying to do something else.

Comment: I've removed all Redux stuff that were working with Apollo's data and now I'm working directly with it. I have to do a refetchQueries some times after running a mutation or the list of affected items don't get updated. So now, I'm just using Redux with data not coming from Apollo.

Comment: That's it! Also, instead of refetching queries, you can update your store locally (for cases like adding or deleting an item from a list, that won't get picked up automatically as said above) using the `update` option in the mutation. (`update`'s docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#directAccess)